# Android Studio App Crashes due to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, crash

My app uses a `RecyclerView` to display a list of items that can be added/deleted using an SQLite DB. In the main screen of the app, the RecyclerView should be shown above 2 buttons which allow the addition/deletion of items.

The app crashes when I enter MainActivity due to the RecyclerView and I can't pinpoint why.

**The log shows the following error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.activities.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference                                                                                                      
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)                                                                                                         
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)                                                                                                      
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)                                                                                                                    
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)                                                                                                       
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)                                                                                                         
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)                                                                                                                    
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                       
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)                                                                                                        
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)                                                                                                      
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                         
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)                                                                                                      
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference                                                                                                       
   at com.example.test.activities.MainActivity.displayData(MainActivity.java:73)                                                                                                     
   at com.example.test.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)                                                                                                        
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)                                                                                                         
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)                                                                                                     
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)                                                                                                    
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)                                                                                                 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)                                                                                                      
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)                                                                                                       
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)                                                                                                   
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)                                                                                                     
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)                                                                                                       
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                       
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)                                                                                                        
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)                                                                                                      
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                         
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)                                                                                                      
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

This **photo** shows the UI without any data populated in the RecyclerView (I had to comment out the code to get the screen to load).
[image: RecyclerViewScreen]

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ItemDatabase db;
    ArrayList<String> itemName, itemQnt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initialize DB
        db = new ItemDatabase(this);
        // Item variables
        Button addItem = findViewById(R.id.addItemBtn);
        Button deleteItem = findViewById(R.id.deleteItemBtn);

        // Set up recyclerview
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        ItemViewAdapter itemViewAdapter = new ItemViewAdapter(this, itemName, itemQnt);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        displayData();

        // Upon clicking on add item button, start the AddItem screen
        addItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddItemActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        // Upon clicking on delete item button, start the DeleteItem screen
        deleteItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeleteItemActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

    }

    private void displayData() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No data present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            itemName.add(cursor.getString(0));
            itemQnt.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemViewHolder.java:**

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView nameView;
    TextView qntView;

    public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameView = nameView.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
        qntView = qntView.findViewById(R.id.qntInput);
    }
}
```

**ItemViewAdapter.java:**

```
public class ItemViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> name, quantity;

    public ItemViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> quantity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_item_inventory, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nameView.setText(String.valueOf(name.get(position)));
        holder.qntView.setText(String.valueOf(quantity.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.size();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <!--Inventory List text-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inventoryListTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:text="@string/inventoryList"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"/>

    <!--WIP: Recyclerview that will link with activity_item_inventory
    to display individual items and make them adjustable. Currently broken-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/inventoryListTxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"/>

    <!--Create button to add item-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addItemBtn"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/addItem"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    <!--Create button to delete item-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteItemBtn"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/deleteItem"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    <!-- Notification Button -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/notificationBtn"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        android:contentDescription="@string/notificationBtnDesc"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_notifications_24"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_item_inventory.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardElevation="12dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <!-- Display item name column-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textItem"
                android:text="@string/itemName"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp" />

            <!-- Display item name input-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameInput"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <!-- Display item quantity column-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textQuantity"
                android:text="@string/itemQnt"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp" />

            <!-- Display item quantity input-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qntInput"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ArrayLists are declared but not initialized before they are used in the function displayData:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at com.example.test.activities.MainActivity.displayData

MainActivity.java

onCreate()

```
ArrayList<String> itemName, itemQnt;
```

…

displayData()

```
itemName.add(cursor.getString(0));
```